# Como criar variáveis dummy

Tags: r

Estou tentando transformar cada variável do meu banco de dados em variáveis dummy:

```
>dados
  X1 X2 X3
1  1  3  1
2  3  2  1
3  3  2  1
4  2  3  2
5  2  3  3
```

Estou tentando criar vetores binários para isso. Mas, não consigo fazer da forma correta.
Como tenho 3 categorias por variável, o número de variáveis dummy é: **k-1 variáveis dummy**. Isso resultaria em 2 variáveis artificiais por variável.

O que eu tentei foi isso:

```
library(mlr)
createDummyFeatures(dados,cols=NULL)

   1 2 3
1  1 0 0
2  0 0 1
3  0 0 1
4  0 1 0
5  0 1 0
6  0 0 1
7  0 1 0
8  0 1 0
9  0 0 1
10 0 0 1
11 1 0 0
12 1 0 0
13 1 0 0
14 0 1 0
15 0 0 1
```

Por que isso me retorna 3 variáveis por variável (pois k-1 variáveis dummy, deveriam ser duas). Além disso, elas estão na mesma coluna! Como faço para resolver estes problemas? Elas deveriam ficar assim:

```
   a b    c d    e f 
1  1 0    0 0    1 0
2  0 0    0 1    1 0
3  0 0    0 1    1 0
4  0 1    0 0    0 1
5  0 1    0 0    0 0
```

Comment: Mas a função `rep` reconhece o algarismo 6 e retorna um vetor de 1. Não está claro para mim o que tu deseja fazer diferente.

Comment: Você pode criar uma função que só dependa do algarismo que você quer transformar em múltiplos números 1, utilizando a função `rep` por dentro dessa sua função.

Comment: Editei a questão para explicar melhor o meu objetivo. Estou tentando criar variáveis dummy. Procurei algo no site, mas não encontrei nada sobre este assunto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O mais próximo que cheguei do resultado que você espera foi utilizando a função `dummyVars` do pacote `caret`. O resultado não foi igual pois o exemplo que você deu não possui o número `1` na coluna `X2`, por isso ela é omitida do resultado final.

Primeiro é preciso construir as variáveis como fator:

```
dados <- data.frame(X1 = as.factor(c(1,3,3,2,2)), X2 = as.factor(c(3,2,2,3,3)), X3 = as.factor(c(1,1,1,2,3)))
```

Depois eu modifiquei a referência das variáveis para chegar no que você espera:

```
dados$X1 <- relevel(dados$X1, ref = 3)
dados$X2 <- relevel(dados$X2, ref = 3)
dados$X3 <- relevel(dados$X3, ref = 3)
```

Por fim, criei as variáveis *dummy* com o pacote `caret`:

```
library(caret)
dummy <- dummyVars(~ ., data = dados, fullRank = T)
```

O resultado é:

```
predict(dummy, dados)

  X1.1 X1.2 X2.3 X3.1 X3.2
1    1    0    1    1    0
2    0    0    0    1    0
3    0    0    0    1    0
4    0    1    1    0    1
5    0    1    1    0    0
```

Comment: joia! Funcionou.